# How to sort manual buckets created in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column :

```
hourly_ticket
(0,1]
[1,2)
[2,3)
[3,4)
```

and so on `till [23,24)`

when I am using this column in a pandas pivot table it is getting re-arranged in a way like: `[0, 1)    [1, 2)  [10, 11)    [11, 12)    [12, 13)    [13, 14)` unlike of how I want which is in ascending order.
How do I fix this? How do i sort it? the `dtype of this columns is "O" which is Object`

Answer (score 0):

The `.sort_values` function can take a `key` function that is applied to the column you wish to sort on.
Assuming the column stores the bins as a `str`, the `parse_hourly_ticket` first strips all brackets and parenthesis for each row, and return the first number in each "bucket" which then are used to sort the dataframe.

```
parse_hourly_ticket = lambda x: x.apply(lambda s: float(s.strip('[]()').split(',')[0]))
df.sort_values('hourly_ticket', key=parse_hourly_ticket)
```